# Laravel redirection through ajax request from blade to controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade file which allows a user to delete certain items by sending an ajax request to the controller.

If all validation on the controller end passes and the item is successfully deleted, I would like for the user to be redirected back to the same page with the page being refreshed however the page isn't being refreshed and nothing seems to be happening

Blade file

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{env('APP_URL')}}/ticket-dashboard/updateTicket",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {"option":option, "status":status,"ticket_id":manual_ticket_id,'completed_id':'{{$user}}',"latest_ticket_log_id":latest_ticket_log_id,_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('-------');
            console.log(data);
            if(data['updated']){
                alert("The selected task was updated and page has to be refreshed before attempting to apply action to ticket again");
            }
            else {
                //Page should have reloaded on controller side
            }
        }
    })
```

Controller file

```
if($validationPasses){
    return redirect()->route('ticket_dashboard');
}
```

Comment: It should redirect from javascript, not controller.

Comment: Then what does the redirect function as provided for by laravel do? return redirect()->route('ticket_dashboard'); @WahyuKristianto

Comment: You can't redirect from controller when using ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($validationPasses){
    return response->json(["status" => "redirect", "url" => "ticket_dashboard"]);
}
```

/////// javascript ////////////

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{env('APP_URL')}}/ticket-dashboard/updateTicket",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {"option":option, "status":status,"ticket_id":manual_ticket_id,'completed_id':'{{$user}}',"latest_ticket_log_id":latest_ticket_log_id,_token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('-------');
            console.log(data);
            if(data['updated']){
                alert("The selected task was updated and page has to be refreshed before attempting to apply action to ticket again");
            }
            else {
                if(data.status === "redirect"){
                   window.location.href = data.url;
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

You need tp response to ajax then you can redirect.

Comment: Whats the reason as to why i cant redirect from the controller?

The json response for URL as indicated in your example isn't a link so the window location href code doesnt work but i get the gist of your example thanks!

Comment: Sorry url should be like that "url" => route("your route here"). But why it is not work because of you ajax still working and waiting response.

Comment: This is similar to what the guy initially commented on my main post. Thanks for taking the time to do up a quick solution, i believe it should work! Will be marking it as the answer for future users